# How to handle multiple payments on multiple bills?

Tags: database-design

I'm stuck with this problem.

I've got these tables:

```
BILL(bill_id, card_id, costumer_id, value)
PAYMENT(payment_id, payment_type, value, bill_id)
```

The costumer can pay multiple cards. My application sum the values from each bill and then the employ charges the costumer for that value.

EXAMPLE:
Lets say Costumer01 has $30 on his card and $50 on his wife's card.
He wants to pay $40 on money and $40 on the credit card.

I want my database to store how much he paid with each payment method. How can I solve this problem?

PS: I can have more than 2 bills being paid together.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really need to know how he paid for particular bill, i'll change PAYMENT table to:

```
 PAYMENT(payment_id, payment_type, value, customer_id)
```

Comment: I want to know how he paid for a particular bill. :/